# Is it possible to launch Chrome Browser with CodeceptJS + PlayWright or CodeceptJS + Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, playwright, codeceptjs

I am able to launch the Chrome browser using Playwright-core and puppeteer-core, But Want to use codeceptjs with Playwright.

Can we user Playwright-core or puppeteer-core with CodeceptJS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been given to installing puppeteer without downloading the chromium binaries [in this issue post](https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/issues/2076#issuecomment-564490915):

```sh
npm config set puppeteer_skip_chromium_download true
npm install puppeteer
```

The same kind of environment variable exists for playwright as described [in their documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/installation/#skip-browser-downloads):

```sh
PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1 npm i -D playwright
```

After that you can install and configure CodeceptJS as usual:

```sh
npm install codeceptjs
npx codeceptjs init
```

Note that there is also [an open issue in the CodeceptJS repository about supporting explicitely `playwright-core`](https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/issues/2663) package, so there is no official way of installing that package directly.